# Google Search Console vs. Google Analytics Data Difference

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

I manage a number of sites for an Agency, and in pretty much all of them I see huge differences in the Search Queries data that you get from Search Console, vs. the integrated one you get in Analytics, after adding the Search Console account.

Everything is different, impressions, clics, CTR, avg. position. On one site in particular, Search Console reports a total of 687,137 impressions, whereas the same Search Console account added in Google Analytics says 2,258,182 impressions. What gives!!!

Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: GA gets it search data from GWT (Search Console) so that does not even make sense to me. I am not saying you are wrong- it just does not make sense. Make sure your accounts are linked correctly is all I can think of.

Comment: They are correctly linked, it's the same Google Account where we add all our client's sites.

Comment: Well, that is a good one!! ;-) I wish I knew or even have half a guess. Sorry. I will have to think about this one a bit to see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We all are facing the same situation while the answer is very simple. I am putting the my experience with discussing with few analyst Guy regarding the same.

**GWT (Search Console) -** This data directly comes from the Google Search repository databases.

&

**GA (Google Analytics) -** This data only counts when your GA Script loaded successfully into the browser. (Clicks, Sessions, etc)

It happened because of the data reflected into account API with different sources.

Comment: Yea - you'd think they'd be one and the same, since GA states you're "connecting" to your Search Console account when you verify ownership. Hopefully they'll add descriptive text on the differences soon. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is more accurate than Google Webmaster. Google Analytics Measures users interactivity on a website. Google Webmaster mostly describe website structure, keyword relevancy and a brief idea about keywords.

Comment: Yes I've heard this.  But the difference is huge isn't it?

Comment: yes. Their Purpose is different.

Comment: Hi Vikas, don't think you understand the question though, however thanks so much for your input!

Comment: Most of all ad blockers extension also block google analytic script. Nothing is pure accurate.