# The difference in the number of GA and GSC clicks

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-search-console

I have a problem that in GA in the tab Acquisition -> Search Console -> Landing pages in the column Clicks I have the value 679, while in the tab Acquisition -> Search Console -> Queries I have the number of clicks 670.

In GSC the number of clicks is 670.

What can be the reason for this difference? I mean only the number of clicks and not the number of sessions.

I have checked it further on the ​example of one of the articles and the difference is e.g. that GSC did not count one keyword which is visible in GA

Comment: See also [Google Search Console vs. Google Analytics Data Difference](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86032/google-search-console-vs-google-analytics-data-difference) which mostly focuses on differences in impressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible reasons for data discrepancies with Search Console data, but a likely reason is:

> To protect user privacy, Search Analytics doesn't show all data. For
> example, we might not track some queries that are made a very small
> number of times or those that contain personal or sensitive
> information.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en